# XSL always creating new ComponentGroup insted of adding the components into the same component group.XSL used in Heat.exe

Tags: xslt, wix, xslt-2.0

```
  I have created this xsl for dynamically create .WXS output.But i am facing one issue like  as per the below xsl it creates component group for each folder.I don't want to create component group for each folder and i need to have only one component group and add all the components into this group.
I have one component gruop  "HelpFiles_Group" as mentioned in the below output and it generates from heat.exe.I have added "extjs","css" folders manually within the same "HelpFiles_Group" group but i am expecting this should be part of XSL..
```

While using the below xsl it is creating different Component groups for "extjs","css" folders.Any idea how can we add all component into the same Component Group? What change required in the below XSL?

### My XSL,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="wix:Fragment/wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Directory">
        <wix:Fragment>
          <wix:ComponentGroup Id="{@Name}">
            <xsl:if test="count(descendant::wix:Component) = 0">
              <wix:Component Id="{@Id}" Directory="{@Id}" Guid="">
                <wix:RemoveFolder Id="{@Name}" On="uninstall" />
                <!--<wix:RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\NgSSimulation" Type="string" Value="NextGen" KeyPath="yes" />-->
              </wix:Component>
            </xsl:if>
          </wix:ComponentGroup>
        </wix:Fragment>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\NgSSimulation" Type="string" Value="SimCentral" KeyPath="yes" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:File">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="KeyPath">
        <xsl:text>no</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Ouput .WXS expected.

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="Simulation_Help">
      <Directory Id="extjs" Name="extjs" />
      <Directory Id="images_1" Name="images" />
      <Directory Id="uilocale" Name="uilocale" />
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="HelpFiles_Group">

      <Component Id="extjs" Guid="{8FB704ED-5A08-42DF-A593-8F04AD8EAB64}" Directory="extjs">
        <RemoveFolder Id="SimSciHelp_extjs" On ="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\SimCentral" Type="string" Value="SimCentral" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="css" Guid="{A5066974-3279-4C45-85EA-F3A7F55343C4}" Directory="css">
        <RemoveFolder Id="css" On ="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\SimCentral" Type="string" Value="SimCentral" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="default" Guid="{BF114032-02E5-49B1-A8FD-F927843A5E7A}" Directory="default">
        <RemoveFolder Id="default" On ="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\SimCentral" Type="string" Value="SimCentral" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="button" Guid="{42BE8034-622B-4C76-8FA1-78DDD151037C}" Directory="button">
        <RemoveFolder Id="button" On ="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\SimCentral" Type="string" Value="SimCentral" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
```

---

Ouput as per new XSL

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <wix:ComponentGroup Id="Simulation_Help">
      <wix:Component Id="extjs" Directory="extjs" Guid="">
        <wix:RemoveFolder Id="extjs" On="uninstall" />
      </wix:Component>
      <wix:Component Id="images_1" Directory="images_1" Guid="">
        <wix:RemoveFolder Id="images" On="uninstall" />
      </wix:Component>
      <wix:Component Id="uilocale" Directory="uilocale" Guid="">
        <wix:RemoveFolder Id="uilocale" On="uninstall" />
      </wix:Component>
    </wix:ComponentGroup>
  </wix:Fragment>
  <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <wix:ComponentGroup Id="uilocale" />
  </wix:Fragment>
  <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <wix:ComponentGroup Id="images_1" />
  </wix:Fragment>
  <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <wix:ComponentGroup Id="tree" />
  </wix:Fragment>
  <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <wix:ComponentGroup Id="toolbar" />
```

---

### It should not create separate Component Group, instead all component id should be within the first component group.

Comment: You have two templates matching **wix:Component**, which is not allowed because the XSLT will not be able to determine which one to use. Is your XSLT sample definitely correct?

Comment: Hi,I have updated the question with my xslt.Please help on this.

Comment: Well, you now have three templates matching **wix:Component** elements! Maybe you are expecting them to be used in different contexts, but at the moment XSLT will not be able to decide which one to use because they all match the same element. Perhaps you could edit your question to show the actual .wxs file, and also your expected output. Or maybe you could explain when you are expecting each template to be used. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the question.I tried to add the <RemoveFolder Id= in line number 10 as mentioned above but it is not adding the tag in .wxs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is that you are creating the **wix:ComponentGroup** elemnts within the **xsl:for-each**

```
  <xsl:for-each select="wix:Fragment/wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Directory">
    <wix:Fragment>
      <wix:ComponentGroup Id="{@Name}">
```

You really only want one **wix:ComponentGroup** for each **wix:DirectoryRef** which means you probably want two nested **xsl:for-each** statements, one for **wix:DirectoryRef** and one nested inside for **wix:Directory**

Try something like this

```
<xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="wix:Fragment/wix:DirectoryRef">
      <wix:Fragment>
        <wix:ComponentGroup Id="{@Id}">
          <xsl:for-each select="wix:Directory">
             <xsl:if test="count(descendant::wix:Component) = 0">
               <wix:Component Id="{@Id}" Directory="{@Id}" Guid="">
                 <wix:RemoveFolder Id="{@Name}" On="uninstall" />
                 <!--<wix:RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\IOM\NgSSimulation" Type="string" Value="NextGen" KeyPath="yes" />-->
               </wix:Component>
             </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </wix:ComponentGroup>
      </wix:Fragment>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi I am creating a .wxs as mentioned above but i need to add RemoveFolder only for Folders and Subfolders How can i do? i think it required to change some existing template from above code.What change required in xslt to include RemoveFolder in the folder and subfolder? not file level

Comment: updated the question...strugling to create the xsl for the above case.pls help on this with snippet

Comment: I think it would help if you amended your question to show a small, but complete, sample of the .wxs file, as well as a sample of the output you are expecting. Thank you!

Comment: XSLT sample i have attached.For  <ComponentGroup Id="HelpFiles_Group"> i have to create component id for each folder with RemoveFolder key.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. It would really help if you showed a small but complete sample of your input XML, and also a sample of the output XML you are expecting. Thank you!

Comment: i have updated the code and entire question  with my xsl,expected output,my output what i have now.

Comment: I have totally changed my answer now. I hope it is what you are looking for!

Comment: It again creating new fragment and new component groups.These new groups should be within the Component group "HelpFiles_Group".I have updated the new XSL outout above section "Ouput as per new XSL".ComponentGroup Id="uilocale", ComponentGroup Id="toolbar" all should be within the HelpFiles_Group".

Comment: It is difficult for me to recreate the issue when I can't see the original WXS document you are working on. Please can you show your input XML. Thank you.

Comment: .Wxs document format is in "Output expected" section.First Component group i can hardcode with name "HelpFiles_Group" but all other component should add to this group without creating new groups.I think we can put a if condition in xsl and write all component to same component group? looks xsl need some change..